# Is there an equivalent for 'command -v' in Windows?

Tags: windows, powershell, unix, command, command-prompt

Is there any equivalent of 'command -v' in windows 10 command prompt?
For example:

```
command -v samtools
/usr/bin/samtools
```

Comment: `where.exe /?` or view [online](http://ss64.com/nt/where.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are in PowerShell, you can use `Get-Command`.

```
(Get-Command -Name cmd -CommandType Application).Source
```